# Is there a term for those large, half-cocked hats with flower-like embellishments British high society seems to favor?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for those half-cocked hats with large flower-like embellishments British high society seems to favor? I'm seeing quite a lot of them watching a live stream of the Royal Wedding, and would like to call them by their proper name.

Comment: Someone has been watching too much wedding coverage?

Comment: @F'x I watched it for the officers and the vestments and the history, not to indulge in gawking at the Royals... ;)

Comment: And by history I mean the ecclesiastical and mediaeval birthed historical traditions, not the need that some feel to be "part" of the Wedding...

Comment: Like this one: "[Poor Camilla looked like a pheasant crash-landed on her head](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/debate/columnists/article-546948/Brunis-pert-pillbox-hat-perfect-Poor-Camilla-looked-like-pheasant-crash-landed-head-.html)" ?

Comment: Wedding? What wedding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean the [Cocktail Hats](http://www.google.it/search?um=1&hl=it&safe=off&biw=1231&bih=666&site=search&tbm=isch&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&q=Cocktail%20Hats)?

**EDIT:**

Then maybe:

- [Capeline](http://www.google.it/search?um=1&hl=it&safe=off&biw=1231&bih=666&site=search&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=Capeline&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=);
- [Cart-wheel hat](http://www.google.it/search?um=1&hl=it&safe=off&biw=1231&bih=666&site=search&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=Cart-wheel%20hat&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=) (When "basic", this is without flowers though);
- [Gainsborough hat](http://www.google.it/search?um=1&hl=it&safe=off&biw=1231&bih=666&site=search&tbm=isch&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&q=Gainsborough%20hat).

The list is taken from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hats_and_headgear).

Comment: Those look similar, but these have quite a wider brim...

Comment: @Billare: I added 3 more and the source, have fun! (I didn't know those names myself, you never stop learning eh) :D

Comment: Tha fancy flowery things alone are called "Fascinators", though I don't know if "Fascinator hats" is valid

Comment: [Google search for Fascinators](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=fascinators&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=1440&bih=799)

Comment: I don't think a "fascinator hat" is possible; see [this article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-1078234/The-Queen-style-Fascinator-sales-soar-majesty-abandons-traditional-wedding-hat.html) about Queen Elisabeth II's fashion which clearly opposes fascinators and hats.

Comment: There are 580,000 entries in Google though... Maybe it's not very common?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could call them *Derby Hats* (although this is also a [synonym for bowler hat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derby_hat) when applied to men).

Depending on which side of the pond you stand, that could mean either

- *[Kentucky Derby Hats](http://www.google.com/search?q=kentucky+derby+hats&hl=en&prmd=ivnsu&tbm=isch&tbo=u)* in the US or
- *[Epsom Derby Hats](http://www.google.com/search?q=epsom+derby+hats&hl=en&prmd=ivnsu&tbm=isch&tbo=u)* in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

try [millinery](http://www.wordnik.com/words/Millinery)

> Articles, especially women's hats,
>   sold by a milliner.